# Symfony 3: FosUserBundle Customizing registration form using custom html classes

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

As I was trying to customize a login form fro FosUSerBundle of my symfony 3 project, therefore I had a look on the FosUSerBundle's default twig templates in order to gen an idea, then I noticed that the twig template provided via vendor (`vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig`) has the following values:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And I noticed that it calls a `{{ form_widget(form) }}` in order to render the form. so I want to know how this method is called and how can I customize the view. Basically I want the and the html classes of the form in order to look like the registration admin AdminLte's One: https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/register.html

Right now what I have done is to create this template `app/Resources/FOSUSerBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig`:

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% set classes='hold-transition register-page'%}

{% block fos_user_content %}

  {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

  <div class="register-box">
    <div class="register-logo">
        <h1>PhotoShare!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="register-box-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
      {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register')}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      {{ form_end(form) }}
  </div>

{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

That extends `app/Resources/FOSUSerBundle/views/layout.html.twig` has the following content:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Photoshare!!{% endblock %}

{% set classes=''%}

{% block body %}
  {% block fos_user_content %}
  {% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock body %}
```

That extends the `app/Resourses/views/base.html.twig` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        {% block stylesheets %}
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}}" >
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/adminlte/adminlte.css')}}" >
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/adminlte/skin-blue.css')}}" >
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />

        {% block javascriptsHeader %}

        {% endblock %}

    </head>
    <body class="{{ classes }}">
      {% block body %}
      {% endblock body %}

      {% block javascriptsFooter %}

      {% endblock javascriptsFooter %}
   </body>
</html>
```

The fields I want to render are the default and the very same that are provided via the default FosUserBundle's administrator form. I want to mess around with the html classes in order to achieve the same look from the template that is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html) is what you need.

You can either create a form theme and use it only in specific templates like your registration form:

```
{% form_theme form 'register-form-theme.html.twig' %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Or you can set a global form theme in `config.yml`:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    # ...
    form_themes:
        - 'form-theme.html.twig'
```

Your form theme then should extend the default div layout provided by symfony:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

You can then override the blocks from this template:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form-theme.html.twig #}
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block form_start -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({ 'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' custom classes')|trim }) %}
    {{ parent() }}
{%- endblock form_start -%}

{%- block form_row -%}
    <div class="custom classes">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}

{%- block form_widget_simple -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({ 'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' custom classes')|trim }) %}
    {{ parent() }}
{%- endblock form_widget_simple -%}
```

Comment: what is the difference between `form_widget_simple` and `form_row`?

Comment: `form_widget_simple` is just the `{{- form_widget(form) -}}` part in the `form_row`. Before and after the actual input field is the label and the errors. Take some time and digg into the form theming system of symfony. It was a little bit confusing to me at first glance but turned out to be quite powerful and not thaaat hard to understand. Saves me a lot of time today.

Comment: In `form_widget_simple` what classes are being set? As fas As I know is that AdminLTE's custom theme each input field has the following eg `              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name">` So where `form-control` class goes?

Comment: Where it says ' custom classes' in my code example... I tried to point that out for you that way... ;)

Comment: There are 2 points that says custom classes one on `div` in `from_row` and one on `form_widget_simple` which one is what the div must have different classes from the input field.

Comment: Take a look at the parent widgets in `form_div_layout.html.twig`. This should explain it. In brief: `form_widget_simple` is the actual `input` field. `form_row` is just a container around the label, the input field and possible errors.